# Page is getting Submit Without Refresh Via Otp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tampermonkey

I got this website when I fill the information and try to send the OTP page reload 
Here's the website:

https://tunisia.blsspainvisa.com/english/book_appointment.php

After you fill the information and click on (Request verification code) and you will know what I mean

What I tried is:

```
$(function () {

  $('#tunisiaThird').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',

        url: 'https://tunisia.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php',

        data: $('#tunisiaThird').serialize(),



            success: function () {
      }
    });

  });
});
```

I'm only a client, so I'm using Tampermonkey to inject.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more about jquery ajax post or get method here:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

And there are tons of questions here if you search you will find tons of examples

Here is a complete example, which is getting error messages from php part and displaying on html form.
Like this: in php : `$error .= 'an error happend';` and ajax `$('#result').html(data.error);`

to display in html.

```
<div id="result"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tunisiaThird').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formValues = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        url:"book_appointment.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:formValues,
        dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
                if(data.error === 'ok'){
                    $('#result').html('Successfuly');
                    $('#tunisiaThird')[0].reset();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location = 'index.php';
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    $('#result').html(data.error);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: im not Sure I understand is this Script to work Cuz it didnt or you are just Giving me A example ?

Comment: its a complete working example, you can use it, but beter to read some examples to learn istead of copy paste, let e change 1 thing then you can use it.

Comment: i only need this one so i Really dont mind Copy Past lol thx 
if u can tell me what is Wrong in my Script please do or Correct me if im wrong

Comment: Done,  you can have it, your code is almost same as mine but half of it.lol, Glad I helped you. Can you  accept answer as helpfull if it does.

Comment: same thing the Page didnt Reload but the Otp Didnt Send to my email :( 
maybe you should take a look how the Site Work ?

Comment: Looks like working :) change url in my aswer to your url like this : book_appointment.php not like this. https://tunisia.blsspainvisa.com/book_appointment.php

Comment: Still not Reciving the Otp on my Email Mate :(

Comment: :) :) This is just ajax part which is just posting data without refreshing page, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting/59490784?noredirect=1#comment105159338_59490784 AND HERE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305164/how-to-send-mail-with-phpmailer-class HOW TO SEND EMAIL.