# Phpmailer and javascript configuration

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

I'm new to the world of programming. My code is shown below.

First question: how do I format the body text? For example, not having all requests in a row but one below the other, etc.

Second question: How can I insert the code to be able to load a file in my contact form, the html code is already present and it works but on the javascript side I can't understand where to insert it.

Last question: I have a news letters acceptance field how do I insert a field that tells me if the user has accepted the news letter?

Thanks a lot to everyone!

```php
    <?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
    $indirizzo = $_POST["indirizzo"];
    $civico = $_POST["civico"];
    $citta = $_POST["citta"];
    $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
    $cap = $_POST["cap"];
    $newsletters = $_POST["newsletters"];

    $body = "Name:" .$name . "<br>Email:" . $email .
        "TelefonoLocale:" . $telefono . "Indirizzo:" . $indirizzo . "Civico:" . $civico . "Città:" . $citta. "Provincia:" . $provincia . "Cap:" . $cap . "newsletters:" . $newsletters;

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings

        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'xxxxxxx';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'xxxxxxxx';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxxxxxx';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = xxxxxx;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('xxxxxx', $name);
        $mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxx');     // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo '<script>
        alert("Messaggio inviato correttamente");
        window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305164/how-to-send-mail-with-phpmailer-class AND here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailerhttps://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer And this one how to get errors by jquery ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489824/jquery-ajax-settimeout-after-form-succes-not-redirecting

Comment: One question at the time... [ask]