# How to stop phpmailer multiple resend on refresh? (and show error message)

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

When i refresh the page the phpmailer always resends the email.
What i did?
Used the  `header("Location: home.php");`

But how can i do the Location to home.php and show my error message 
$error = "Thank you for message!";

```
if($mail->send()){
    header("Location: home.php");
    $error = "Thank you for message!";
} else {
    $error .= "Error {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

the problem is that when i do the header it does not show me the error message...

```
<div class="text-center impact">
<?php echo $error; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Do if statement and ask for button submited `if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'];` see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59489824/12232340 and get errors https://stackoverflow.com/a/59305499/12232340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `GET-parameter` so you can check it when the page reloads. Try this code example:

```
if($mail->send()){
    header("Location: home.php?success");
} else {
    $error .= "Error {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

And on your page:

```
<div class="text-center impact">
<?php echo isset($_GET['success']) ? "Thank you for message!" : $error; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not see it, because your browser do redirect immediately, before you can see it.

Super simple solution will be to redirect to:
header("Location: send-confirmation.php");

with the information that message has been sent.
Of course you can do more advanced solution and pass apropiate parameter to home page or to use cookies/session on your phpmailer page to avoid duplicate sending.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `$error` variable between your pages, so when you echo it, it's not defined and you'll get no output. You need to either pass it through a URL query parameter:

```
header("Location: home.php?error=" . rawurlencode($error));
```

and then retrieve it on that page:

```
echo $_GET['error'];
```

or alternatively pass it via a session variable (probably the better choice):

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = $error;
header("Location: home.php");
```

and then:

```
echo $_SESSION['error'];
```